# SKPhysicsbody error on collision swift

Tags: xcode, swift, skphysicsbody

i have to following code that makes a custom `physicsBody` for my enemy.
see the code below:

```
let offsetX = CGFloat(Enemy.frame.size.width * Enemy.anchorPoint.x)
let offsetY = CGFloat(Enemy.frame.size.height * Enemy.anchorPoint.y)

let path = CGPathCreateMutable()

CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 25 - offsetX, 73 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 32 - offsetX, 72 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 45 - offsetX, 66 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 47 - offsetX, 63 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 43 - offsetX, 11 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 25 - offsetX, 2 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 11 - offsetX, 15 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 5 - offsetX, 29 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 5 - offsetX, 30 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 3 - offsetX, 44 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 3 - offsetX, 51 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 7 - offsetX, 65 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 9 - offsetX, 67 - offsetY)
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 15 - offsetX, 70 - offsetY)

CGPathCloseSubpath(path)

Enemy.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(polygonFromPath: path)
```

when i run this code my `physicsBody` is half the size of my picture. and sits at the bottom left of the picture. how do i fix this?

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out if you multiply all your values it should work!
see the next line of code:

```
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, 11*2 - offsetX, 15*2 - offsetY)
```